# Implementing zoom on a fixed point, javascript/canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zoom in on a point (using scale and translate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916081/zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate)

I want to implement zooming on the mouse pointer with the mouse wheel. That is scaling the image while the point under the mouse pointer stays fixed.

Here is my code, which doesn't work very well

```
var scala = 1 + event.wheelDelta / 1000;
canvas.context.translate(-canvas.mouse.x * ( scala - 1 ) / canvas.scale,-canvas.mouse.y * ( scala - 1 ) / canvas.scale);
canvas.context.scale(scala,scala);
canvas.scale *= scala;
//canvas.scale is my variable that is initially set to 1.
//canvas.mouse is my variable that represents the mouse position relative to the canvas
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything, or doesn't behave correctly

Comment: doesn't behave correctly, mouse.x is in window coordinates while translate uses the scaled coordinates, that's where I think is the problem.

Comment: also if I use scale(1.3,1.3);scale(0.7,0.7); the object returns to the original position but 1*1.3*0.7!=1

Comment: mouse.x is in canvas coordinates, or screen coordinates?

Comment: 1.3*0.7 is nearly 1 (0.91). Can you put the full code on http://www.jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it and the answer is here: [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916081/zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate)

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at anything else, you'll need 2 translates: one before to move the mouse point to (0,0), and one after to move (0,0) (now with the zoomed picture) to where the mouse was.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to do a `canvas.context.restore()` after each redraw, if you are saving the zoom level.