# Zooming with canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-animation

In a test application i have a canvas with a simple rectangle on it. The method *draw* is called every 100ms.

as you can see from the code i'm using the Mousewheel to scale everything. What happens now is, that everything is scaled, but i.e. when the rectangle is at 10px,10px and i have the mouse right over it the rectangle is not under the mouse anymore after scaling. (Which is of course right because all units are scaled up to.

But what i want to is, that the mouseposition is the "center of the zooming action" like in google maps so the content which is under the mouse before scaling, is under the mouse afterwards as well. I made a few attemps with translating, but i can't figure out, how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var scroll = 0;
        var scale = 1.0;


                    /** This is high-level function.
         * It must react to delta being more/less than zero.
         */
        function handle(delta) {

                var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                scroll = delta;
                if(scroll > 0)
                {
                    scale += 0.2;
                }
                if(scroll < 0)
                {
                    scale -= 0.2;
                }


        }

        /** Event handler for mouse wheel event.
         */
        function wheel(event){
                var delta = 0;
                if (!event) /* For IE. */
                        event = window.event;
                if (event.wheelDelta) { /* IE/Opera. */
                        delta = event.wheelDelta/120;
                } else if (event.detail) { /** Mozilla case. */
                        /** In Mozilla, sign of delta is different than in IE.
                         * Also, delta is multiple of 3.
                         */
                        delta = -event.detail/3;
                }
                /** If delta is nonzero, handle it.
                 * Basically, delta is now positive if wheel was scrolled up,
                 * and negative, if wheel was scrolled down.
                 */
                if (delta)
                        handle(delta);
                /** Prevent default actions caused by mouse wheel.
                 * That might be ugly, but we handle scrolls somehow
                 * anyway, so don't bother here..
                 */
                if (event.preventDefault)
                        event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = false;
        }

        /** Initialization code. 
         * If you use your own event management code, change it as required.
         */
        if (window.addEventListener)
                /** DOMMouseScroll is for mozilla. */
                window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
        /** IE/Opera. */
        window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

        var drawX = 0;
        var drawY = 0;
        var overX = 0;
        var overY = 0;

         function startCanvas()
         {
             var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
             var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
             ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
             ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;                 
             setInterval(draw,100);
         }

         function draw()
         {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.scale(scale,scale);
            ctx.fillRect(drawX,drawY,20,20);
            //ctx.translate(-scale,-scale);
            ctx.restore();
            ctx.font="20pt Arial";  
            ctx.fillText(scale+":"+drawX,0,150);                
         }

         function canvasClick(event)
         {
            console.log(event.layerX+"/"+scale);
            drawX = event.layerX/scale;
            drawY = event.layerY/scale;
         }

         function canvasOver(event)
         {
            console.log("over");
            overX = event.layerX;
            overY = event.layerY;
         }

    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zoom in on a point (using scale and translate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916081/zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's actually a non-trivial math question, usually known as a "zoom point"

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916081/zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate) where another canvas user wanted to do the same thing and found a way.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var scale = 1;
var originx = 0;
var originy = 0;

function draw(){
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(originx,originy,800/scale,600/scale);
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(50,50,100,100);
}
setInterval(draw,100);

canvas.onmousewheel = function (event){
    var mousex = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mousey = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    var wheel = event.wheelDelta/120;//n or -n

    var zoom = 1 + wheel/2;

    context.translate(
        originx,
        originy
    );
    context.scale(zoom,zoom);
    context.translate(
        -( mousex / scale + originx - mousex / ( scale * zoom ) ),
        -( mousey / scale + originy - mousey / ( scale * zoom ) )
    );

    originx = ( mousex / scale + originx - mousex / ( scale * zoom ) );
    originy = ( mousey / scale + originy - mousey / ( scale * zoom ) );
    scale *= zoom;
}

</script>
```