# HTML5 Framework for a custom product editor

Tags: html, html5-canvas, sproutcore, cappuccino, easeljs

I'm looking into several html5 frameworks for a project that would be in some ways similar to the [iMakeMyCase](http://custom.case-mate.com/imakemycase/) editor.

The main features that have to be implemented:

- choosing a predefined background
- placement of multiple pre-defined elements with drag and drop
- elements have to be resizable, rotatable
- undo/redo
- elements have to have ability to bring them forward/backwards (like layers)
- zooming of the whole canvas (that one could be tricky ... any suggestions?)
- ability to save the elements placement
- get a .png preview of the finished product (can you somehow capture the canvas to a regular image)

The frameworks that I have been loooking so far:

**cappuccino**

Looks promising and the projects that have been made with it cover 90% of functionality that I need. I'm not sure about ObjectiveJ though ...

**sproutcore**

I didn't see lots of examples, but if apple made the whole iCloud with it, then it sure has to be powerful. But I have a feeling that a lot of implementation would be needed to get the required features covered. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**easeljs**

The examples look cool and if you combine them, you almost have everything covered. Probably my favourite at the moment.

What's your opinion on these frameworks and are they suitable for the project? Any others that I have missed? Any suggestions are really welcome to help me choose the right tool for the job.

Thx.

Comment: If you understand Javascript and object oriented programming you can learn Objective-J in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

For your zooming Functionality i found same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775168/zooming-with-canvas)

and for a png preview of your image you can do something like that

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
//here you got the png image show just create an element and show this preview there
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

Comment: Thx, I didn't know that you can create .png like that. Perfect.