# HTML Canvas Zooming Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, zooming

Recently, I decided to delve into the world of HTML5 and the canvas and I have run into an issue that I cannot figure out how to solve.

I am using the zoom technique that was mentioned in **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916081/zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate)**, as I need to be able to zoom into a specific point.

**However, the issue I have encountered is when you zoom into an area, and then perform a large mouse movement, and then zoom out. The entire viewpoint and objects become skewed.** *(Objects that were previously occupying the entire canvas, are now partially or sometimes not visible at all.)*

I am assuming that the zoom in towards a point function is using the mouse position upon zooming out, which is causing these issues.

**Here is a demo to get an idea of the issue:** *(again to reproduce, just zoom in move the mouse a reasonable distance and zoom out)*

[**Not-Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/4a26B/1/)

Comment: By the way, lots of people don't have mouse wheels, or a mouse, me included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as designed.  When you apply your context translation based on the mouse position it will zoom centered on that position.

To achieve the fixed zoom out behavior I think you want you need to set the mouseX and mouseY only on zoom in and then use the last mouseX/mouseY (or possibly the center of the canvas, or some point in between) for zoom out.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BtPxk/1/)

Comment: Thanks RSG - I updated the demo with something a bit more complicated, more apt to an actual situation. If you have any advice, the same issue is still there for that one. :)

Comment: You need to move the declaration for mousex/mousey outside of the function- it's still updating it on zoom out.  This doesn't completely fix the logic for the translation positioning- I think the offset needs to be a function of the current translation and zoom level to ensure it always appears in bounds.  I'll fiddle more at lunch.  Very nice routine for the skyline.

Comment: It appears to be breaking after the 2nd zoom - it's almost like you would have to store the previous points in a array and push and pop off with zoom ins/outs.

Comment: I thought about that, it could get weird if you zoomed all the way in, partially out, in on a new point, and then all the way out.  It would jump when it got to the point in the array where the user changed direction.

Comment: That's true - it's a bit of a strange problem. I almost wish I could make those buildings always drawn in the same area, as I am trying to add a "panning" function into it as well, which shouldn't complicate things (I hope) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096921/html5-panning-based-on-mouse-movement