# Panning a DIV within a DIV based on mousemove

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know of a plugin that would allow me to place a DIV (that DIV having various other elements) within a DIV and allow the parent DIV to be 'panned' based on relative mouse movement?

I've seen loads of examples for panning an IMG within a DIV, but haven't seen exactly what I'm after.

Thanks.

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096921/html5-panning-based-on-mouse-movement work for you?

Comment: I'd prefer something that doesn't rely too much on HTML5 (for cross browser reasons)

Comment: something like jquery ui draggable?

Comment: you are not looking for pan, you need a content slider.

Comment: zdrsh, thanks to your proper terminology, managed to find a fantastic solution here - http://articles.tutorboy.com/2010/10/05/mouseover-auto-scroller-menu-using-jquery-and-css/ - have hacked it to do horizontal as well, and it's working perfect.  My sincere thanks.