# How to detect panning in mobile in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gesture, panning

On my mobile phone, I have a web app, that shows a 3d model in the center of it. I would like it if I could drag my finger horizontally anywhere on screen or vertically anywhere, like panning, and get a value from it, some delta, from start to current location while dragging. These values will rotate the model in z and y axis, but that part is irrelavent. What I don't get is how to detect panning with fingers on mobile.

I tried this example
[HTML5 Panning based on Mouse Movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096921/html5-panning-based-on-mouse-movement)

but it doesn't seem to work with fingers.