# Smooth "zoom to cursor" animation with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, zooming, kineticjs

Based on other SO questions (see credits at the bottom), I came up with a way to animate the "zoom to cursor" effect with KineticJS.

**Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dariospagnolo/8ag9h2nv/).**

The relevant section is here :

```
zoom: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var evt = event.originalEvent,
        mx = evt.clientX - ui.stage.getX(),
        my = evt.clientY - ui.stage.getY(),
        zoom = (ui.zoomFactor - (evt.wheelDelta < 0 ? 0.4 : -0.4)),
        newscale = ui.scale * zoom;

    ui.origin.x = mx / ui.scale + ui.origin.x - mx / newscale;
    ui.origin.y = my / ui.scale + ui.origin.y - my / newscale;

    zoomTween = new Kinetic.Tween({
        node: ui.layer, 
        duration: 0.8,
        offsetX: ui.origin.x,
        offsetY: ui.origin.y,
        scaleX: newscale,
        scaleY: newscale
    });
    zoomTween.play();

    ui.scale *= zoom;
}
```

**What should I change in my code to avoid the "bouncing" effect, especially when zooming in/out fast ?**

My code is a fork of this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FnwS5/117/) (attached to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18795691/4066116)) with 3 minor modifications :

- uses KineticJS 5.1.0
- uses a Tween to animate the offset and scale properties
- layer is being offseted/scaled instead of stage because stage wasn't playing well with Tween

Other credits :

- [Zoom Canvas to Mouse Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189968/zoom-canvas-to-mouse-cursor/5526721#5526721) : excellent canvas-only solution
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13663169/4066116 : KineticJS version

Comment: Your fiddle works perfect for me.

Comment: @lavrton: thank you for looking at my code. Weird that you don't see the bouncing problem. I captured it in a screencast : https://vid.me/yVJ I guess it also has something to do with multiple tweens playing simultaneously. This happens when you wheel just faster than very slowly.