# Pinch to zoom with Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, image, zooming, pinch, hammer.js

I want a pinch to Zoom function for an image. I want it to zoom in the area where the fingers are.

My index is only

```
<div id="wrapper" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);overflow: hidden;">

</div>
```

And my script for zooming and scrolling is similar [with this example](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/examples/pinchzoom.html). I have made a few changes to fit with my project

My problem is in

```
        case 'transform':
            rotation = last_rotation + ev.gesture.rotation;
            scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(last_scale * ev.gesture.scale, 10));
            break;
```

How can I change it so that it doesn't zoom into the center of the picture but at place where the first finger have touch the display?

Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example with hammer.js and tap. As you tap it will zoom in at the point where you tapped. The event data is common for all gestures so switching from tap to pinch should work. It is a good example to work on. You may need to increase the scale step as you pinch. It has been tested on chrome(v30) and firefox (v24).
*It is based on the solution mentioned at the thread,
[Zoom in on a point (using scale and translate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916081/zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate)
as you will see an alternative could also be to use canvas.*

**HTML**

```
<div style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);overflow: hidden;" class="zoomable">
    <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01842/landscape-rainbow_1842437i.jpg" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {


        var scale = 1; // scale of the image
        var xLast = 0; // last x location on the screen
        var yLast = 0; // last y location on the screen
        var xImage = 0; // last x location on the image
        var yImage = 0; // last y location on the image

        Hammer($('.zoomable img').get(0)).on("tap", function (event) {

            var posX = event.gesture.center.pageX;
            var posY = event.gesture.center.pageY;


            // find current location on screen 
            var xScreen = posX; //- $(this).offset().left;
            var yScreen = posY; //- $(this).offset().top;

            // find current location on the image at the current scale
            xImage = xImage + ((xScreen - xLast) / scale);
            yImage = yImage + ((yScreen - yLast) / scale);

            scale++;

            // determine the location on the screen at the new scale
            var xNew = (xScreen - xImage) / scale;
            var yNew = (yScreen - yImage) / scale;

            // save the current screen location
            xLast = xScreen;
            yLast = yScreen;

            // redraw
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')' + 'translate(' + xNew + 'px, ' + yNew + 'px' + ')')
                .css('-webkit-transform-origin', xImage + 'px ' + yImage + 'px').css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + scale + ') translate(' + xNew + 'px, ' + yNew + 'px)').css('-moz-transform-origin', xImage + 'px ' + yImage + 'px')
                .css('-o-transform', 'scale(' + scale + ') translate(' + xNew + 'px, ' + yNew + 'px)').css('-o-transform-origin', xImage + 'px ' + yImage + 'px').css('transform', 'scale(' + scale + ') translate(' + xNew + 'px, ' + yNew + 'px)');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SySZL/

Comment: Will try it tomorrow! looks good this give me a little hint how i get the current position of the page.
I will report if it works for me after testing :)

Comment: @user2664120 the current pinch position you get from event.gesture.center.pageX and event.gesture.center.pageY. The zooming position depends on the pinch position and how much zoomed the image is. This is what the code of the answer does, inside hammer tap callback function .

Comment: Hi thank you have change the code a bit to fit with my current code with your example i got it to work great thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [Pinch Zoom and Pan with HammerJS demo](http://bl.ocks.org/redgeoff/raw/6be0295e6ebf18649966d48768398252/). This example has been tested on Android, iOS and Windows Phone.

You can find the source code at [Pinch Zoom and Pan with HammerJS](https://gist.github.com/redgeoff/6be0295e6ebf18649966d48768398252).

For your convenience, here is the source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <title>Pinch Zoom</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>

    <div style="height:150px;background-color:#eeeeee">
      Ignore this area. Space is needed to test on the iPhone simulator as pinch simulation on the
      iPhone simulator requires the target to be near the middle of the screen and we only respect
      touch events in the image area. This space is not needed in production.
    </div>

    <style>

      .pinch-zoom-container {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 300px;
      }

      .pinch-zoom-image {
        width: 100%;
      }

    </style>

    <script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>

    <script>

      var MIN_SCALE = 1; // 1=scaling when first loaded
      var MAX_SCALE = 64;

      // HammerJS fires "pinch" and "pan" events that are cumulative in nature and not
      // deltas. Therefore, we need to store the "last" values of scale, x and y so that we can
      // adjust the UI accordingly. It isn't until the "pinchend" and "panend" events are received
      // that we can set the "last" values.

      // Our "raw" coordinates are not scaled. This allows us to only have to modify our stored
      // coordinates when the UI is updated. It also simplifies our calculations as these
      // coordinates are without respect to the current scale.

      var imgWidth = null;
      var imgHeight = null;
      var viewportWidth = null;
      var viewportHeight = null;
      var scale = null;
      var lastScale = null;
      var container = null;
      var img = null;
      var x = 0;
      var lastX = 0;
      var y = 0;
      var lastY = 0;
      var pinchCenter = null;

      // We need to disable the following event handlers so that the browser doesn't try to
      // automatically handle our image drag gestures.
      var disableImgEventHandlers = function () {
        var events = ['onclick', 'onmousedown', 'onmousemove', 'onmouseout', 'onmouseover',
                      'onmouseup', 'ondblclick', 'onfocus', 'onblur'];

        events.forEach(function (event) {
          img[event] = function () {
            return false;
          };
        });
      };

      // Traverse the DOM to calculate the absolute position of an element
      var absolutePosition = function (el) {
        var x = 0,
          y = 0;

        while (el !== null) {
          x += el.offsetLeft;
          y += el.offsetTop;
          el = el.offsetParent;
        }

        return { x: x, y: y };
      };

      var restrictScale = function (scale) {
        if (scale < MIN_SCALE) {
          scale = MIN_SCALE;
        } else if (scale > MAX_SCALE) {
          scale = MAX_SCALE;
        }
        return scale;
      };

      var restrictRawPos = function (pos, viewportDim, imgDim) {
        if (pos < viewportDim/scale - imgDim) { // too far left/up?
          pos = viewportDim/scale - imgDim;
        } else if (pos > 0) { // too far right/down?
          pos = 0;
        }
        return pos;
      };

      var updateLastPos = function (deltaX, deltaY) {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
      };

      var translate = function (deltaX, deltaY) {
        // We restrict to the min of the viewport width/height or current width/height as the
        // current width/height may be smaller than the viewport width/height

        var newX = restrictRawPos(lastX + deltaX/scale,
                                  Math.min(viewportWidth, curWidth), imgWidth);
        x = newX;
        img.style.marginLeft = Math.ceil(newX*scale) + 'px';

        var newY = restrictRawPos(lastY + deltaY/scale,
                                  Math.min(viewportHeight, curHeight), imgHeight);
        y = newY;
        img.style.marginTop = Math.ceil(newY*scale) + 'px';
      };

      var zoom = function (scaleBy) {
        scale = restrictScale(lastScale*scaleBy);

        curWidth = imgWidth*scale;
        curHeight = imgHeight*scale;

        img.style.width = Math.ceil(curWidth) + 'px';
        img.style.height = Math.ceil(curHeight) + 'px';

        // Adjust margins to make sure that we aren't out of bounds
        translate(0, 0);
      };

      var rawCenter = function (e) {
        var pos = absolutePosition(container);

        // We need to account for the scroll position
        var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset ? window.pageXOffset : document.body.scrollLeft;
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : document.body.scrollTop;

        var zoomX = -x + (e.center.x - pos.x + scrollLeft)/scale;
        var zoomY = -y + (e.center.y - pos.y + scrollTop)/scale;

        return { x: zoomX, y: zoomY };
      };

      var updateLastScale = function () {
        lastScale = scale;
      };

      var zoomAround = function (scaleBy, rawZoomX, rawZoomY, doNotUpdateLast) {
        // Zoom
        zoom(scaleBy);

        // New raw center of viewport
        var rawCenterX = -x + Math.min(viewportWidth, curWidth)/2/scale;
        var rawCenterY = -y + Math.min(viewportHeight, curHeight)/2/scale;

        // Delta
        var deltaX = (rawCenterX - rawZoomX)*scale;
        var deltaY = (rawCenterY - rawZoomY)*scale;

        // Translate back to zoom center
        translate(deltaX, deltaY);

        if (!doNotUpdateLast) {
          updateLastScale();
          updateLastPos();
        }
      };

      var zoomCenter = function (scaleBy) {
        // Center of viewport
        var zoomX = -x + Math.min(viewportWidth, curWidth)/2/scale;
        var zoomY = -y + Math.min(viewportHeight, curHeight)/2/scale;

        zoomAround(scaleBy, zoomX, zoomY);
      };

      var zoomIn = function () {
        zoomCenter(2);
      };

      var zoomOut = function () {
        zoomCenter(1/2);
      };

      var onLoad = function () {

        img = document.getElementById('pinch-zoom-image-id');
        container = img.parentElement;

        disableImgEventHandlers();

        imgWidth = img.width;
        imgHeight = img.height;
        viewportWidth = img.offsetWidth;
        scale = viewportWidth/imgWidth;
        lastScale = scale;
        viewportHeight = img.parentElement.offsetHeight;
        curWidth = imgWidth*scale;
        curHeight = imgHeight*scale;

        var hammer = new Hammer(container, {
          domEvents: true
        });

        hammer.get('pinch').set({
          enable: true
        });

        hammer.on('pan', function (e) {
          translate(e.deltaX, e.deltaY);
        });

        hammer.on('panend', function (e) {
          updateLastPos();
        });

        hammer.on('pinch', function (e) {

          // We only calculate the pinch center on the first pinch event as we want the center to
          // stay consistent during the entire pinch
          if (pinchCenter === null) {
            pinchCenter = rawCenter(e);
            var offsetX = pinchCenter.x*scale - (-x*scale + Math.min(viewportWidth, curWidth)/2);
            var offsetY = pinchCenter.y*scale - (-y*scale + Math.min(viewportHeight, curHeight)/2);
            pinchCenterOffset = { x: offsetX, y: offsetY };
          }

          // When the user pinch zooms, she/he expects the pinch center to remain in the same
          // relative location of the screen. To achieve this, the raw zoom center is calculated by
          // first storing the pinch center and the scaled offset to the current center of the
          // image. The new scale is then used to calculate the zoom center. This has the effect of
          // actually translating the zoom center on each pinch zoom event.
          var newScale = restrictScale(scale*e.scale);
          var zoomX = pinchCenter.x*newScale - pinchCenterOffset.x;
          var zoomY = pinchCenter.y*newScale - pinchCenterOffset.y;
          var zoomCenter = { x: zoomX/newScale, y: zoomY/newScale };

          zoomAround(e.scale, zoomCenter.x, zoomCenter.y, true);
        });

        hammer.on('pinchend', function (e) {
          updateLastScale();
          updateLastPos();
          pinchCenter = null;
        });

        hammer.on('doubletap', function (e) {
          var c = rawCenter(e);
          zoomAround(2, c.x, c.y);
        });

      };

    </script>

    <button onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
    <button onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>

    <div class="pinch-zoom-container">
      <img id="pinch-zoom-image-id" class="pinch-zoom-image" onload="onLoad()"
           src="https://hammerjs.github.io/assets/img/pano-1.jpg">
    </div>


  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The behavior is laggy and ugly comparing with the native iOS pinch to zoom and pan.