# Google Chrome maximum zoom level?

Tags: google-chrome, zooming, pinchzoom

Is there any way to change maximum zoom level in Google Chrome? Sometimes I need to view the details of images, especially SVG, but Chrome's zoom maximum is 500%.

Additionally, I'd like to increase the limit for the zoom gesture on touchpad, because this is way below 500%.

Comment: This is the way it is done in Firefox: http://techrena.net/change-firefox-maximum-minimum-zoom-levels/

Answer (score 18):

You can create a chrome extension to inject this code on the page you want to zoom:

```
document.body.style.zoom = "800%"
```

You could make the extension change the value at any time as well with a little bit of work.

Example of this working on google.com : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdDRH.png

Left is 800% right is 500% for comparison.

Will probably mess up formatting on a lot of pages but this is expected at that level of zoom.

To make this a working chrome extension you would need two files. manifest.json and zoom.js as follows:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "ZoomTest",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.1",

  "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"],
            "js": ["zoom.js"]
        }
    ]

}
```

zoom.js

```
document.body.style.zoom = "800%"
```

Put them both in a folder and then enter "chrome://extensions/" in your chrome address bar. From there check "Developer mode" and click "load unpack extension". Select the folder you put the files in from the dialog. That should do it. Now google.com should be zoomed at 800%!

To learn more about what you can do from there see: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

Comment: Thanks. I know I can do it this way, but I'd need something to simply zoom in at the selected point and, also simply, zoom out.

Comment: Perhaps the answers here would help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916081/zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate

Comment: You also could try scrolling to a point relative to the mouse position after setting the zoom level. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: Well, this is a workaround, but it certainly deserves a bounty, because it solves the question for me. I haven't thought I could hack it via a short simple extension or via `document.body.style.zoom = "800%"` in developer console.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph There's another problem with this solution. Body is not always present. I usually need this zoom feature for images, not for websites.

Comment: @RoboRobok When you open an image in Chrome, the `<body>` gets created for you. That's because it's browser, not image viewer. I've just checked it for an image once more, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Not for SVG :)

Comment: @RoboRobok `document.rootElement.style.zoom = '800%';` then :)

Answer (score 4):

I recently stumbled across this little trick. I've only tested it on a Mac with a trackpad.

Use Chrome's default zoom to 500%. Now use a "pinch-to-zoom" gesture on the trackpad to zoom in an additional 500%.

This can be done in either order, for a total of 1000%