# Get relative X and Y on transforming canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas which contains some rectangles (which are created by rotating the context etc.). There is an image which is loaded on to the canvas and then the rectangles map a certain area (for which the co-ordinates come from AJAX Service).

I need to know which rectangle the client has clicked. Sometimes it works when the canvas isn't transformed, but once I transform the canvas (by zooming or dragging), the mouse X Y position doesn't stay relative to the canvas.

My requirement is to show alert if the user clicks inside the rectangle. Even when zoomed or panned

Here is the JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/a5t0w1dj/2/

(See the red line from Minnesota to South Dakota)

Following is the code that generates my rectangle:

```
var rect = (function() {
  // constructor
  function rect(id, x, y, angle, width, height, fill, stroke, strokewidth) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.id = id;
    this.width = width < 0 ? width * -1 : width;
    this.height = height < 0 ? height * -1 : height;
    this.fill = fill || "#ff0000";
    this.stroke = stroke || "#00ff00";
    this.strokewidth = strokewidth || 1;
    this.angle = angle || 0;
    this.redraw(this.x, this.y);
    return (this);
  }
  rect.prototype.redraw = function(x, y) {
      this.x = x || this.x;
      this.y = y || this.y;
      this.draw(this.stroke);
      return (this);
    }
    //
  rect.prototype.highlight = function(x, y) {
      this.x = x || this.x;
      this.y = y || this.y;
      this.draw(this.ctx, "#00ffff");
      return (this);
    }
    //
  rect.prototype.draw = function(stroke) {
      //ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
      ctx.rotate(this.angle);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
      ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
      ctx.lineWidth = this.strokewidth;
      ctx.rect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.restore();
    }
    //
  rect.prototype.isPointInside = function(x, y) {
    console.log("X: " + x + ', Y: ' + y);
    console.log(this.x + ', ' + (this.x + this.width) + ', ' + this.y + ', ' + (this.y + this.height));
    return (x >= this.x && x <= this.x + this.width && y >= this.y && y <= this.y + this.height);
  }


  return rect;
})();
```

I have hit a dead end here, can anyone please help me out with this.
Thanks alot.

**EDIT**

I have been trying different techniques, even tried the one in the comments but it didn't work.

All I need is a message on mouse click when the user clicks anywhere on the line

Comment: Do you see a red line from Minnesota to South Dakota?

Comment: This answer addresses your problem. Solution is to calculate the inverse transform and apply that to the mouse coordinates to get the world coordinates.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34598847/3877726

Comment: Thanks @Blindman67 I will try it out.

Comment: @Blindman67 I tried that but it didn't work for me. Any ideas on how it's going to work