# Getting correct coordinates after pinch zoom for drawing lines in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas, touch-event

I'm developing an application in which I'm pasting images, doing drawing and painting on canvas. This app can also have pinch zoomin zoomout feature by HammerJS, the canvas can drag/pan it to different location. My problem is: I can't get the correct canvas coordinates after scaling or dragging the canvas. I want to draw finger paint after the canvas is scaled or dragged but unable to retrieve the right place where i've touched..:( Also I'm new bee. Here is the code for pinch zoom in and zoom out

```
var scaleFoctor = 1;
function hammerIt(elm) {  
  hammertime = new Hammer(elm, {});
  hammertime.get('pinch').set({
    enable: true
  });
  var posX = 0,
  posY = 0,
  scale = 1,
  last_scale = 1,
  last_posX = 0,
  last_posY = 0,
  max_pos_x = 0,
  max_pos_y = 0,
  transform = "",
  el = elm;

  if($('#pinchZoomInZoomOut').find('#pinchZoomInZoomOutBg').hasClass('btnIconHighLight')) {
    hammertime.on('doubletap pan pinch panend pinchend panleft panright tap press', function(ev) {
        //console.log("ev.type -- "+ev.type);
    if (ev.type == "doubletap") {
      transform =
      "translate3d(0, 0, 0) " +
      "scale3d(2, 2, 1) ";
      scale = 2;
      last_scale = 2;
      try {
        if (window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform').toString() != "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)") {
          transform =
          "translate3d(0, 0, 0) " +
          "scale3d(1, 1, 1) ";
          scale = 1;
          last_scale = 1;
        }
      } catch (err) {}
      el.style.webkitTransform = transform;
      transform = "";
    }

  if($('#pinchZoomInZoomOut').find('#pinchZoomInZoomOutBg').hasClass('btnIconHighLight')) {
        //pan    
      if (scale != 1) {  
            //console.log("pan ev.type -- "+ev.type);
          posX = last_posX + ev.deltaX;
          posY = last_posY + ev.deltaY;
            //console.log("posX - "+posX);
            //console.log("posY - "+posY);
            max_pos_x = Math.ceil((scale - 1) * el.clientWidth / 2);
            max_pos_y = Math.ceil((scale - 1) * el.clientHeight / 2);
            //console.log("max_pos_x - "+max_pos_x);
            //console.log("max_pos_y - "+max_pos_y);
            if (posX > max_pos_x) {
              posX = max_pos_x;
            }
            if (posX < -max_pos_x) {
              posX = -max_pos_x;
            }
            if (posY > max_pos_y) {
              posY = max_pos_y;
            }
            if (posY < -max_pos_y) {
              posY = -max_pos_y;
            }
          }
        }else{

        }
    //pinch
    if (ev.type == "pinch") {
      startDrawing = false;
      scale = Math.max(.999, Math.min(last_scale * (ev.scale), 4));
      scaleFoctor = scale;
        //console.log("pinch scale -- "+scale);
      }
      if(ev.type == "pinchend"){
        //console.log("pinchend stopped 1 ")
        last_scale = scale;
        //console.log("pinchend last_scale -- "+last_scale);
        scaleFoctor = scale;
    }  
    //panend  
    if(ev.type == "panend"){
        //console.log("pinchend stopped 2 ")
      last_posX = posX < max_pos_x ? posX : max_pos_x;
      last_posY = posY < max_pos_y ? posY : max_pos_y;
    }  
    if (scale != 1) {
        ///console.log("pinchend stopped")
      transform =
      "translate3d(" + posX + "px," + posY + "px, 0) " +
      "scale3d(" + scale + ", " + scale + ", 1)";
    }
    if (transform) {
      el.style.webkitTransform = transform;
    }  
  });
}
```

and below code is for getting touch points and drawing on canvas

```
// listen for touch events
$("#wrapperCanvas").touchstart(function (e) {
 // var x = e.clientX;
   // var y = e.clientY;

   //alert("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
  if($('#pinchZoomInZoomOut').find('#pinchZoomInZoomOutBg').hasClass('btnIconHighLight')) {
    console.log("touchstart Zoom enabled startDrawing -- "+startDrawing);
    console.log("touchstart Zoom enabled startDrawing -- "+scaleFoctor);
    startDrawing = false;
    pinchZoomInZoomOutOn();
  }else{
    startDrawing = true;
    console.log("touchstart marker enabled startDrawing -- "+startDrawing);
    newCtx = document.getElementById('drawOnScreen').getContext("2d"); 

    e.preventDefault();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("drawOnScreen");
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    //clipBounds_canvas = canvas.getClipBounds();
    var out = {x:0, y:0};
    if(e.type == 'touchstart' || e.type == 'touchmove' || e.type == 'touchend' || e.type == 'touchcancel'){
      var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
      console.log("touch.pageX - "+touch.pageX);
      console.log("touch.pageY - "+touch.pageY);
      if(scaleFoctor != 1){
        out.x = touch.pageX/scaleFoctor;
        out.y = touch.pageY/scaleFoctor; 
      }else{
        out.x = touch.pageX/scaleFoctor - rect.left;
        out.y = touch.pageY/scaleFoctor - rect.top;  
      }
    }
    var startX = parseInt(out.x);
    var startY = parseInt(out.y);
    Draw(startX, startY, false);
  }
  //start drawing on canvas
});
$("#wrapperCanvas").touchmove(function (e) {
  //started drawing on canvas
  if (startDrawing) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("drawOnScreen");
    //var ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var out = {x:0, y:0};
    if(e.type == 'touchstart' || e.type == 'touchmove' || e.type == 'touchend' || e.type == 'touchcancel'){
      var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
      //out.x = touch.pageX/scaleFoctor - rect.left;
      //out.y = touch.pageY/scaleFoctor - rect.top;
      if(scaleFoctor != 1){
        out.x = touch.pageX/scaleFoctor;
        out.y = touch.pageY/scaleFoctor; 
      }else{
        out.x = touch.pageX/scaleFoctor - rect.left;
        out.y = touch.pageY/scaleFoctor - rect.top;  
      }
    }
    var startX = parseInt(out.x);//parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var startY = parseInt(out.y);//parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    Draw(startX, startY, true);
      }
});
$("#wrapperCanvas").touchend(function (e) {
   //handleMouseUp(e);
  startDrawing = false;
  cPush();
});
```

Please help me to draw on canvas after zoomin/zoomout.

Comment: Take a look at [this answerr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas/17130415#17130415) at the two last methods - you should be able to use the code there for touch events as well. The coordinates needs to be adjusted to match the bitmap (by default it matches the element which is not necessarily of the same size).

Comment: @K3N I have tried this.. This is not working..

Comment: Did you try with inverse matrix?

Comment: @K3N I have tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597160/html-canvas-mouse-position-after-scale-and-translate but there is no luck.. this giving me 7 digits co-ordinates\