# Canvas draw points localized to clicked area after scale, rotate and translation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, canvas

I have a bit of a complicated question (I did a lot of research but wasn't able to find what I'm looking for), basically I'm building a labeling tool where i get a set of images and i want to be able to click the corners of objects and create a point where the user clicks.

### Few things to note (I've already done these)

- Images can be any orientation and i need to rotate them (rotate from an orientation)
- The image should start out scaled to fit the canvas (setting a scale to "zoom out" from image and canvas sizes)
- Users can "pan" around (translation based on **arrow keys**)
- Users can zoom in and out on the image (scale with **shift + arrow up/down**)
- Users can reset an image back to center (**spacebar** centers, **shift + spacebar** resets zoom initial and re-centers)

The issue I have now is I'm building the click portion (where I draw a point at the cursor location). I have tried multiple things to put the mouse coordinates at the correct location (accounting for scale, translation and rotation) and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it. Would love some help or pointers as to how to basically **inverse the rotation, scale and translation** I've applied to get the point in the correct place.

---

To give some real context around this I made a Codepen to show whats happening.

## [Codepen to see it live with the arrow keys / clicks on the canvas](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGgzWp)

```
const red = '#ff0000';

class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement
  private image = new Image
  private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null
  private data: any
  private orientation: number = 270

  private moveKeys: {[key: number]: number} = {}
  private cw: number
  private ch: number
  private scaleFactor: number = 1.00
  private startX: number
  private startY: number
  private panX: number
  private panY: number
  private isShiftPressed: boolean
  private defaultScaleFactor: number = 1.00

  private imagePoints: number[][] = []

  loadImage = (url: string) => {
    this.image.onload = () => {
      const iw = this.orientation === 0 || this.orientation === 180 ? this.image.width : this.image.height
      const ih = this.orientation === 0 || this.orientation === 180 ? this.image.height : this.image.width
      const smaller = Math.min(this.canvas.width / iw, this.canvas.height / ih)
      this.defaultScaleFactor = smaller
      this.scaleFactor = smaller  
    }
    this.image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYvnM.jpg'
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp)
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown)
    // window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeCanvas)
    this.canvas.removeEventListener('click', this.handleCanvasClick)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.isShiftPressed = false
    document.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp)
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown)
    // window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeCanvas) // dont need for this example
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
    const elem = document.getElementById('canvasContainer')
    if (!elem) return
  
    const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect()

    this.canvas.addEventListener('click', this.handleCanvasClick)
    this.canvas.width = rect.width
    this.canvas.height = rect.height
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
    this.cw = this.canvas.width
    this.ch = this.canvas.height

    this.startX = -(this.cw / 2)
    this.startY = -(this.ch / 2)
    this.panX = this.startX
    this.panY = this.startY
    
    this.loadImage()

  }
  handleCanvasClick = (e) => {
    let rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    let x = e.clientX - rect.left
    let y = e.clientY - rect.top
    this.imagePoints.push([x, y])
  }

  animate = () => {
    Object.keys(this.moveKeys).forEach( key => {
      this.handleMovement(key, this.moveKeys[key])
    })
    this.drawTranslated()
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
  }
  handleMovement = (key, quantity) => {
    const moveUnit = 20
    switch (parseInt(key)) {
      case 32: // spacebar
        this.panX = this.startX
        this.panY = this.startY
        if (this.isShiftPressed) {
          this.scaleFactor = this.defaultScaleFactor
        }
        break
      case 37: // left
        if (this.orientation === 90 || this.orientation === 270) {
          this.panY -= moveUnit
        } else {
          this.panX -= moveUnit
        }
        break
      case 38: // up
        if (this.isShiftPressed) {
          this.scaleFactor *= 1.1
        } else {
          if (this.orientation === 90 || this.orientation === 270) {
            this.panX += moveUnit
          } else {
            this.panY += moveUnit
          }
        }
        break
      case 39: // right
        if (this.orientation === 90 || this.orientation === 270) {
          this.panY += moveUnit
        } else {
          this.panX += moveUnit
        }
        break
      case 40: // down
        if (this.isShiftPressed) {
          this.scaleFactor /= 1.1
        } else {
          if (this.orientation === 90 || this.orientation === 270) {
            this.panX -= moveUnit
          } else {
            this.panY -= moveUnit
          }
        }
        break
      default:
        break
    }
  }

  handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    if (e.shiftKey || e.keyCode === 16) {
      this.isShiftPressed = false
    }
    delete this.moveKeys[e.keyCode]
  }
  handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (e.shiftKey || e.keyCode === 16) {
      this.isShiftPressed = true
    }
    e.keyCode in this.moveKeys ? this.moveKeys[e.keyCode] += 1 : this.moveKeys[e.keyCode] = 1
  }

  drawTranslated = () => {
    if (!this.ctx) return
    const ctx = this.ctx
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.cw, this.ch)
    ctx.save()
    ctx.translate(this.cw / 2, this.ch / 2)
    ctx.rotate(this.orientation * Math.PI / 180)
    ctx.scale(this.scaleFactor, this.scaleFactor)
    ctx.translate(this.panX, this.panY)

    const transformedWidth = this.canvas.width / 2 - this.image.width / 2
    const transformedHeight = this.canvas.height / 2 - this.image.height / 2
    ctx.drawImage(
      this.image,
      transformedWidth,
      transformedHeight
    )
    
    const pointSize = 10
    if (this.imagePoints.length > 0) {
      this.imagePoints.forEach( ([x, y]) => {
        ctx.fillStyle = red
        ctx.beginPath()
        // Obviously the x and y here need to be transformed to work with the current scale, rotation and translation. But I'm stuck here!
        ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.fill()
      })
    }
    ctx.restore()
  }
  handleResetUserClicks = () => {
    this.imagePoints = []
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <div>Use arrow keys to pan the canvas, shift + up / down to zoom, spacebar to reset</div>
        <div id="canvasContainer">
          <canvas ref={this.assignCameraRef} id="canvasElement" style={{ position: 'absolute' }} ref={this.assignCameraRef} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleResetUserClicks}>Reset Clicks</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
  assignCameraRef = (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => this.canvas = canvas
}
```

Please ignore the lack of defined props and the few hardcoded values (like orientation). I removed a bit of code and abstracted this to be more generic and part of that meant hardcoding the image url to a dummy one I found online and setting some of the parameters for that image as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Inverting the transform

[Inverse transform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598847/3877726.) to find world coordinates.

World coordinates are in this case the image pixel coords, and the function `toWorld` will convert from canvas coords to world coords.

However you translate to `cx`,`cy`, rotate, scale and then translate by pan. You will need to multiply the pan coords by the matrix of the above 3 transforms and add that to the last two values of the matrix before you calculate the inverse transform.

**Note** you have panned twice once for `this.panX`, `this.panY` and then you pan by `transformedWidth` and `transformedHeight` the function below needs the complete pan `this.panX + transformedWidth` and `this.panY + transformedHeight` as the last two arguments.

The modified function from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598847/3877726.) is

```
// NOTE rotate is in radians
// with panX, and panY added
var matrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0];
var invMatrix = [1,0,0,1];
function createMatrix(x, y, scale, rotate, panX, panY){
    var m = matrix; // just to make it easier to type and read
    var im = invMatrix; // just to make it easier to type and read

    // create the rotation and scale parts of the matrix
    m[3] =   m[0] = Math.cos(rotate) * scale;
    m[2] = -(m[1] = Math.sin(rotate) * scale);

    // add the translation
    m[4] = x;
    m[5] = y;

    // transform pan and add to the position part of the matrix
    m[4] += panX * m[0] + panY * m[2];
    m[5] += panX * m[1] + panY * m[3];    

    //=====================================
    // calculate the inverse transformation

    // first get the cross product of x axis and y axis
    cross = m[0] * m[3] - m[1] * m[2];

    // now get the inverted axis
    im[0] =  m[3] / cross;
    im[1] = -m[1] / cross;
    im[2] = -m[2] / cross;
    im[3] =  m[0] / cross;
 }
```

You can then use the `toWorld` function from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598847/3877726.) to get the world coordinates (coordinates in image space)

Comment: Thanks for your help / answer! I'm having some trouble integrating it, i'm going to keep working on this and when i get it done i'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Figured it out! :) just needed to take some time understanding what each piece was doing in the matrix and also how to account for an image offset. Do you mind if I edit your answer with the final solution for other passers by?