# Calculate CSS transform displacement while scaling around origin point using react-use-gesture

Tags: css, reactjs, transform

I'm creating a zoomable and "pannable" canvas by using `useWheel` from react-use-gesture.

The progress is good so far, until I tried to zoom around origin point (which is the mouse position).

[image: See how it's jumping after enable around origin]

I'm having trouble calculating the position displacement to accommodate the changes caused by scaling around a different origin point.

Here's a code sandbox (check App.js around line 60):
https://codesandbox.io/s/usewheel-zoom-pan-stackoverflow-27o0l

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solved!

Borrowed the solution from here and applied it to my react app
[How to zoom on a point with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097552/how-to-zoom-on-a-point-with-javascript)

The takeaway is that I don't rely on `transform-origin` anymore, because changing it is what caused the jump.  The solution now calculates the new origin point and scales towards it.

#### For Reference (this code doesn't work in code snippets here because of modules, try it in code sandbox)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useWheel } from "react-use-gesture";
import clamp from "lodash/clamp";

import "./styles.css";

const STEP = 0.995;
const MAX_SCALE = 5;
const MIN_SCALE = 0.25;

export default function App() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState(true);

  const canvasRef = React.useRef();

  const [canvasTransform, setCanvasTransform] = React.useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    originCenterX: window.innerWidth / 2,
    originCenterY: window.innerHeight / 2,
    wheeling: false,
    scale: 1
  });

  // Set the drag hook and define component movement based on gesture data
  const bind = useWheel(
    ({ wheeling, metaKey, delta: [deltaX, deltaY], event }) => {
      if (metaKey && event) {
        const factor = deltaY;

        const { clientX, clientY } = event;

        const scaleChanged = Math.pow(STEP, factor);

        const newScale = clamp(
          scaleChanged * canvasTransform.scale,
          MIN_SCALE,
          MAX_SCALE
        );

        const rect = canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        const currentCenterX = rect.x + rect.width / 2;
        const currentCenterY = rect.y + rect.height / 2;

        const mousePosToCurrentCenterDistanceX = clientX - currentCenterX;
        const mousePosToCurrentCenterDistanceY = clientY - currentCenterY;

        const newCenterX =
          currentCenterX +
          mousePosToCurrentCenterDistanceX * (1 - scaleChanged);
        const newCenterY =
          currentCenterY +
          mousePosToCurrentCenterDistanceY * (1 - scaleChanged);

        // All we are doing above is: getting the target center, then calculate the offset from origin center.
        const offsetX = newCenterX - canvasTransform.originCenterX;
        const offsetY = newCenterY - canvasTransform.originCenterY;

        if (newScale !== canvasTransform.scale) {
          setCanvasTransform({
            ...canvasTransform,
            scale: newScale,
            x: offsetX,
            y: offsetY,
            scaleChanged,
            currentCenterX,
            currentCenterY,
            wheeling
          });
        }
      } else {
        setCanvasTransform({
          ...canvasTransform,
          x: canvasTransform.x - deltaX,
          y: canvasTransform.y - deltaY,
          wheeling
        });
      }
    }
  );

  return (
    <div className="outer" {...bind()}>
      <div
        className="inner"
        style={{
          transform: `translateX(${canvasTransform.x}px) translateY(${
            canvasTransform.y
          }px) scale3d(${canvasTransform.scale}, ${canvasTransform.scale}, 1)`
        }}
        ref={canvasRef}
        id="canvas"
      >
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
      <span>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={() => setIsChecked(!isChecked)}
        />{" "}
        Around Mouse
      </span>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(canvasTransform, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Inter, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
    "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji",
    "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  overscroll-behavior-x: none;
  overscroll-behavior-y: none;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f0f4f7 !important;
}

div > div {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

div > div > div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eee 0.1em, transparent 0.1em),
    linear-gradient(90deg, #eee 0.1em, transparent 0.1em);
  background-size: 3em 3em;
}

span {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

span input {
  font-size: 16px;
}

pre {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
 <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
 <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
 <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
 <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
 <noscript>
  You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
 </noscript>
 <div id="root"></div>
 <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```