# HTML 5 Canvas - Get real coordinate when zooming

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transform, zooming

I finally achieved to implement a zoomable and panning canvas using this code as a base https://stackoverflow.com/a/3151987/5221943 .
Now I need to detect the real coordinate where the user clicked inside the canvas. I don't know how to convert the mouse page coordinate to the real world coordinate taking into account the user has already zoomed or panned the canvas. Any suggestion here?

Answer (score 0):

Here the code for gating the coordinates of the canvas

```js
Call the DumpInfo function in the html canvas tag like 
 <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="200" onmousedown="DumpInfo(event)"></canvas>
Bellow two functions defined 
 <script type = "text/javascript" >
    function DumpInfo(event) {
        var info = document.getElementById("canvas");
    //info.innerHTML += event.type + ", ";
        var pos = getMousePos(info, event);
        alert(pos.x);
        alert(pos.y);
        }
        function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
                y: evt.clientY - rect.top
            };
        }
    </script>
```